# while no se ejecuta

Tags: c, bucles

En el siguiente código no se llega a ejecutar nunca el segundo `while` ¿cual es el motivo?

```
int main(){

    int a,b;
    int producto=0;
    int cociente=0;

    printf ("Escribe primer número.\n");
    scanf ("%d", &a);
    printf ("Escribe segundo número.\n");
    scanf ("%d", &b);

    printf ("Suma: %d.\n", a+b);
    printf ("Resta: %d.\n", a-b);

    while (a!=0 && b!=0){
      producto+=b;
      a--;
    }
    printf ("Producto: %d.\n", producto);

    while (a>= b){
        a=a-b;
        cociente++;
    }
    printf ("División: %d.\n", cociente);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el valor de `a` al terminar el primer bucle?

Comment: a lo ingresa el usuario.

Comment: La suma, resta y producto hace bien. La división no ejecuta el while.

Comment: Lo raro es que si saco el primer while, el segundo lo ejecuta sin problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El segundo bucle nunca se ejecutara por el `a--;` del primer bucle. Permiteme clarifico.

El primer bucle se encarga corre mientras `a` y `b` no sean `0` (Inicialmente asumo que has utilizado valores mayores a 0). La unica manera de que salga del bucle, juzgando el codigo es que la variable `a` llege a ser 0, lo cual logras conseguirlo decrementandola con `a--;`. Una vez se ejecuta ese bucle, el valor de `a` sera siempre de `0`.

Ahora, cuando llegas al segundo bucle, la condicion inicial nunca se cumple. `b` siempre sera mayor a `0`, y como `a` es `0`, nunca se ejecuta el codigo en su interior.

La unica manera que el segundo bucle sea ejecutado es si `b` es `0` o negativo. No importando si `b` es `0` o negativo, te encontraras con un bucle infinito, porque `a` no cambiara su valor (restarle `0`), o se incrementara (restarle un numero negativo, que se traduce a una suma). `a` siempre sera mayor que `b`.

Comment: Perfecto! Ahora sí lo entiendo! Gracias!

Comment: @Adri genial! Ahora puedes aceptar la respuesta para marcar tu pregunta como resuelta =)

Answer (score 1):

En el primer bucle tenemos:

```
while (a!=0 && b!=0){
  producto+=b;
  a--;
}
```

Es decir, el bucle se repetirá mientras `a` y `b` sean distinto de cero... pero dentro del bucle no actualizamos `b` ... luego el bucle se repetirá indefinidamente... este bucle solo tiene que tener en cuenta el valor de `a`:

```
while (a!=0){
  producto+=b;
  a--;
}
```

Aunque, claro, si el valor de `a` tienes que usarlo también en la división te convendría copiar su valor para no perderlo:

```
// opcion 1
int i=a;
while( i!=0 )
{
  producto += b;
  i--;
}

// opcion 2
for( int i=a; i!=0; i--){
  producto+=b;
}
```

Aunque, si no es una restricción del ejercicio, tal vez prefieras calcular el producto directamente:

```
producto = a*b;
```